# Water overflow control system

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, electric-motor, motor

I want to connect simple floating overflow control switch with a heavy duty relay duty to heavy motor, direct simple footing burn out on heavy load, with type of relay will be suitable?

Comment: What does "direct simple footing burn out on heavy load" mean?

Answer (score 1):

The keyword you are looking for is contactor. That is the name for relays designed for high current loads.

Check the Locked Rotor Amps (LRA) of the motor and size the contactor to that. That is the current spike the contactor is attempting to switch.

Don't confuse that number with the running load Amps (RLA) which is substantially lower and is the current the motor is rated to draw continuously.